# How viable is production of magnesium oxide and sulfuric acid from Epsom salt?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, separation-techniques

Epsom salt $(\ce{MgSO4})$ is really cheap (less than 0.5 €/kg), whereas $98\,\%$ or better grade magnesia $(\ce{MgO})$ is much more expensive (3 to 4 €/kg).

Is it possible to convert magnesium sulfate $(\ce{MgSO4})$ back to magnesium oxide $(\ce{MgO})$ and sulfuric acid $(\ce{H2SO4})?$ How difficult and economically viable would that be given the necessity of the efficient separation of the products $(\ce{MgO}$ and $\ce{H2SO4})$ from each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, at 1124 °C [magnesium sulfate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_sulfate) decomposes to magnesium oxide without melting producing sulfur trioxide as the side product. [[1](https://doi.org/10.1021/ie102554f)]

Magnesium sulfate can also be reduced to magnesium oxide using a reducing agent like hydrogen or carbon monoxide. [[2](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01913973)]

#### References

1. Scheidema, M. N.; Taskinen, P. Decomposition Thermodynamics of Magnesium Sulfate. *Ind. Eng. Chem. Res.* **2011**, 50 (16), 9550–9556. DOI: [10.1021/ie102554f](https://doi.org/10.1021/ie102554f).
2. Plewa, J.; Steindor, J. Kinetics of Reduction of Magnesium Sulfate by Carbon Oxide. *J. Therm. Anal.* **1987**, 32 (6), 1809–1820. DOI: [10.1007/BF01913973](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01913973).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In example 2, is it sufficient for me to add as a Carbon source the fuel I use to burn the Magnesium Sulfate? Say for example I use a propane fire to burn the Magnesium Sulfate, is the added Carbon from the propane enough? Or for that matter any other hydro-carbon fuel?

Comment: You have to use pure carbon